# Symfony How Fetch Object from database and show this in header on all page

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

How can i fetch all object from database in mysql and show this in header on all page in my site

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Take a look at [How to Embed Controllers in a Template](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html). Create a controller to return the object and render that controller in `base.html.twig`. Extend that template in remaining templates.